# Using system level functions in a notebook server container

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm attempting to deploy JupyterHub using this repository as a starting place: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-deploy-docker

The good news is that I am able to successfully deploy JupyterHub, login, and start spawning notebook servers for users. Additionally these notebook server are functioning as expected.

The next step was to customize the notebook image to better suit my use case. To do this, I modified the 'Dockerfile' found inside of the 'singleuser' directory. It now looks like this:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
USER root
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache requests fastapi pydantic pytest six pymlconf authlib python-dotenv multiping ping3
```

After booting up JupyterHub once again, the goal was to use the ping3 library to try and ping some services in our lab. However, this fails with a permission error as shown below.

Code in Jupyter Notebook:

```py
from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
ping('google.com', unit='ms')
```

Error message:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3ca020a44cd6> in <module>
      1 from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
----> 2 ping('google.com', unit='ms')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ping3.py in ping(dest_addr, timeout, unit, src_addr, ttl, seq, size)
    163         PingError: Any PingError will raise again if `ping3.EXCEPTIONS` is True.
    164     """
--> 165     with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) as sock:
    166         sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
    167         if src_addr:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/socket.py in __init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
    149             if proto == -1:
    150                 proto = 0
--> 151         _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
    152         self._io_refs = 0
    153         self._closed = False

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestions or guidance is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a `PermissionError`, which means you need the privilege of superuser/admin/root to send out the ICMP ping package.